# Unidata query in Java

Tags: java, sql, jpa, u2, unidata

I am totally new to Unidata. I am trying to write a Java application that can query records from Unidata. I downloaded U2 Clients package and installed UniDK. I followed this [example](http://www.pickwiki.com/cgi-bin/wiki.pl?UniObjectsTest). I was able to get a single record by key/ID from the file in Unidata using the libraries in asjava.zip.

I came across the U2 Clients documentation which suggests about using JPA. I am wondering if there is any other options that I can write database query to get list of records with WHERE condition without implementing JPA. I am looking for something similar with using Php to write MySQL query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. First you will want to learn a little bit about 'UniQuery', which is the UniData database's query langauge. You can find that in the [manuals on the Rocket Software site](http://u2.rocketsoftware.com/resources/technical-documentation/view?show=UniData7.3).

As an example, let's say you have a file called `customers` and fields called `name` and `age1

```
SELECT customers WITH name LIKE "Dan..." AND age GT "20"
```

This select statement will generate a list of record IDs that have a `name` starting with Dan and have an `age` greater than 20.

In your code, you will need to execute the SELECT statement first. Assuming `udSess` is the session you created:

```
UniCommand cmd = udSess.command(); // Create an object to run the command
cmd.setCommand("SELECT customers WITH name LIKE 'Dan...' AND age GT '20'")
cmd.exec()

UniSelectList sl = udSess.selectList(0);

while (!sl.isLastRecordRead())
{
   UniString recordID = sl.next();
   // Read your record here, using recordID
}
```

Comment: No problem. At this point, UniCommand. We do have a native UniJPA driver, but unfortunately it only works on Java 6 at this time. We are working on making it work for Java 7.

Comment: I see...I was trying out cmd.setCommand("LIST CUSTOMER");. It didn't work. Does UniCommand only work with 'SELECT' or do I need to plugin additional libraries?

Comment: I tried to query NAME, CITY from CUSTOMER table using UniCommand. Unicommand's reponse is empty. Am I missing anything here? Thanks.

Comment: After `exec`, if you do `String s = cmd.response();` you should get the response. Having said that, it would be strange using LIST in a non console application.

Comment: yeah...i was able to print out `cmd.response()`. However, how can I parse this string of response into an array or a dictionary? OR can I use SELECT to get attribute values? But I was reading through the UniQuery, I did not find anywhere that suggests SELECT can return a selection of attribute values. I was thinking if I should SELECT which returns a list of record ID, loop through the list of ID, and find the relevant attribute values using `unifile.read(key)` to get the fields of each record. But I find this inefficient. Do you have any recommendation on how I can approach this?

Comment: Yes you can. Look at the UniQuery command Reference Manual for the `BSELECT` verb. Alternatively, type `HELP BSELECT` at the command prompt

Answer (score 3):

A late followup to a good answer: if you have a unidata programmer on staff, it may be better to make a call to a subroutine where you just pass parameters to get what you need.  Sort of like calling a stored procedure in other languages.  It's not a requirement at all, but it can be a good approach of you have a java programmer and a unidata/pick programmer working together on a project...

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to need to access the Unidata database from Java on a regular basis, there is a product from Rocket (the owners of Unidata) called "UniObjects for Java" which comprises a class library to access Unidata, including logging in, performing queries and calling BASIC subroutines.  Most developers I have worked with who need to do this use this product.

https://docs.rocketsoftware.com/nxt/gateway.dll/RKBnew20/unidata/previous%20versions/v7.2/unidata_uniobjectsjavadevguide_v72.pdf